# Change access editors to viewers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadhsheet where i have many users with editor access , I looking for Apps Script to change the access of editors to viewer while i am modifying the file . Apps Script because it will save time changing the access of all users manually.
I tried this script but it allows for one user only
function

I tried this script but it allows for one user only

```js
function ed2view() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var editorArray = ss.getEditors();
  var userMail = editorArray[1].getEmail();
  ss.removeEditor(editorArray[1]);
  ss.addViewer(userMail);
}
```

I tried to put it in a loop but still it didnt worked

```js
function ediRem() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var eOwn = ss.getOwner().getEmail();
  var eDit = ss.getEditors();
  for (var i = 0; i <= eDit.length; i++) {
    ss.removeEditor(eDit[i]);
    ss.addViewer(eDit[i]);
  }
}
```

it gives me error

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- About `I tried to put it in a loop but still it didnt worked` and `it gives me error`, I think that the reason of your issue is due to `(var i =0 ; i <= eDit.length ; i++ )`. In this case, `i` is over the length of the array of `eDit`. In this case, it is required to be `(var i =0 ; i < eDit.length ; i++)`.
- And, in this case, the owner can be ignored.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function ediRem() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var eOwn = ss.getOwner().getEmail();
  var eDit = ss.getEditors().filter(e => e.getEmail() != eOwn);
  for (var i = 0; i < eDit.length; i++) {
    ss.removeEditor(eDit[i]);
    ss.addViewer(eDit[i]);
  }
}
```

- By this modification, all editors except for the owner are changed to the viewers.

Comment: @Niki Niki Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.